# Preventing default keystroke actions in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I'm attempting to override <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> in Internet Explorer 10, but can't seem to figure out how to do it. I've mocked up a  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmcmahen/hSTFP/)  with some very simple code that works in Chrome (on my Mac, at least). But running this in IE 10 and using <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> still brings up the print dialog box.

Here's my simple code:

```
$('.test').on('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey){
        $('body').append('ctrl p pressed'); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        return false; 
    }        
});​
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: I have submitted a bug with Microsoft Connect -> https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/780963/preventing-default-behavior-of-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Thanks. I never did discover a solution to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent the default behaviour

- use [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of [addEventListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- set `event.keyCode` to 0
- return false

For example. (Prevent default behaviour for Ctrl+O and Ctrl+P)

```
/*jslint browser: true */
(function scriptInitScript() {
    "use strict";

    document.attachEvent("onkeydown", function handleKeyDown(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 79: // o
            case 80: // p
                event.keyCode = 0;
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

}());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aQeCZ/8/)

Please note. jQuery 1.9 uses `addEventListener` if available.  [See in github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/event.js#L105).

Comment: Great work! I thought we were beyond this sort of thing with the latest versions of IE...

Comment: on IE11 document.attachEvent(...) is no longer supported, so you have to check if it's available first 
`if (document.attachEvent) { document.attachEvent(...); }`